# Prove that the transitive closure of the relation $R \subseteq \mathcal{P(\mathbb{N})} \times \mathcal{P(\mathbb{N})}$ is a partial order

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, relations, order-theory

Consider the relation $R \subseteq \mathcal{P(\mathbb{N})} \times \mathcal{P(\mathbb{N})}$ where, for any $X \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and $Y \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, $(X,Y) \in R$ if and only if there exist $u,v \in X$ such that $Y=X \cup \{u+v\}$. For example, $(\{1,2\}, \{1,2,3\}) \in R$ and $(\{1,2\}, \{1,2,4\}) \in R$, but $(\{1,2\}, \{1,2,5\}) \notin R$.

The problem is to prove whether the transitive closure of the relation $R$ is a partial order, and, if so, to find minimal, maximal, minimum, and maximum elements.

I couldn't figure out what the transitive closure looks like, but some doubts that raised were:

1. Since $\emptyset \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and $\emptyset$ is not related to any other set (even itself I think?), does this already break the properties of a partial order? Shouldn't the properties hold for any subset of $\mathbb{N}$, in particular $\emptyset$?
2. What about singleton sets such as $\{1\} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$? Certainly, $(\{1\},\{1\}) \notin R$ because I cannot pick two elements that sum up to $1$. If I haven't missed anything, this remains true in the transitive closure, so can I claim right away that it's not reflexive, and therefore not a partial order?

I think the exercise would not ask for minimals, maximals, etc., if the transitive closure wasn't a partial order (or maybe not?). At first, I thought the singleton sets were the minimal elements, but then there is the question in (2). If the transitive closure is not a partial order, I cannot even speak of minimals, right? In addition, since the relation is defined on an infinite set, there would not be a maximum element. As for the maximals, I have no idea, I believe they don't exist either.

Comment: And if the question were about the reflexive and transitive closure of the relation $R$?

Comment: Maybe $R$ is meant to be a partial order on its *domain* only and $\emptyset$ and singletons will not be in the domain? Just speculating, don't know if your text covers such ideas..

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I haven't thought about it. Indeed, if I want the transitive closure to be a partial order, then we are looking for the reflexive-transitive closure, otherwise it'd not be reflexive, right? Interesting observation.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma What do you mean by partial order *on its domain*? Since *every* element has to be related to itself (by reflexivity), aren't we implicitly assuming that $Dom(R)=\mathcal{P({\mathbb{N}})}$?

Comment: @LucasPeres - Yes, in my opinion the question makes sense only if you consider the reflexive-transitive closure of $R$. I mean, the transitive closure of $R$ is not a partial order, because it is not reflexive, as you correctly observed. Do you see how to answer the questions for the reflexive-transitive closure of $R$?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Well, if I'm looking for the reflexive-transitive closure, then I need a $S \supseteq R$ that is reflexive besides transitive. At first I thought I'd be able to discard the empty set and singleton sets, but now my doubts are even more salient. haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S'$ be the *transitive* closure of $R$. As correctly said in the OP, $R$ and hence $S'$ are not reflexive (since $(\{1\},\{1\}) \notin R$), thus $S'$ is *not an order* (I assume that an order is a reflexive, transitive and antisymmetric binary relation).

The question is interesting if we consider instead the reflexive-transitive closure of $R$.

---

Let $S$ be the *reflexive-transitive* closure of $R$, that is,
$$
(X,Y) \in S \iff \exists \, n \in \mathbb{N} : X = X_0, \ Y = X_n, \ (X_i, X_{i+1}) \in R \ \ \forall \, 0 \leq i < n
$$
(note that for $n = 0$ we have $(X,X) \in S$, so $S$ is reflexive).

Let us see that $S$ is an *order*. As $S$ is reflexive and transitive by construction. Thus, we only have to prove that $S$ is *antisymmetric*.

First, note that $R$ is antisymmetric.
Indeed, if $(X,Y) \in R$ and $(Y,X) \in R$ then $Y = X \cup \{x + x'\}$ for some $x, x' \in X$ and $X = Y \cup \{y + y'\}$; in particular $X \subseteq Y$ and $Y \subseteq X$, and therefore $X = Y$.

From the antisymmetry of $R$, it easily follows that $S$ is antisymmetric, and hence $S$ is an order.

---

The order $S$ is *not total*.
For instance, $\emptyset$ is comparable only with itself (indeed, there is no $X \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $(X,\emptyset) \in R$ or $(\emptyset, X) \in R$, so we only have $(\emptyset, \emptyset) \in S$ by reflexivity). This also means that there are *not maximum or minimum* elements for $S$ and that $\emptyset$ is a *maximal* and *minimal* element for $S$.

Another subset of $\mathbb{N}$ that is comparable only with istelf is
$\{0\}$ (indeed, for every $X \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, if $(X,\{0\}) \in R$ or $(\{0\}, X) \in R$ then $X = \{0\}$). This also means that $\{0\}$ is a *maximal* and *minimal* element for $S$.

In general, what are the *maximal elements* for $S$? All and only the maximal elements for $S$ are the subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ that are closed under addition (a formal proof of this requires some knowledge on elementary number theory and deserves another post). Some examples are $\emptyset$ and $\{0\}$, but also $\mathbb{N}$ and $2\mathbb{N} = \{2n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $2\mathbb{N} \smallsetminus \{0,2\}$, and so on (the list is quite long...).

In general, what are the *minimal elements* for $S$? All and only the minimal elements for $S$ are the sets $X \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ whose elements are *"linearly independent"*, that is, for ever $x \in X \smallsetminus \{0\}$, there are not $x_1, \dots, x_k \in X$ such that $x = n_1 \cdot x_1 + \dots + n_k \cdot x_k$ for some $n_1, \dots, n_k > 0$ (again, a formal proof of this requires some knowledge on elementary number theory and deserves another post). Some examples are $\emptyset$ and every singleton subset of $\mathbb{N}$ and $\{2, 5\}$, but not $\{2,5,7\}$ or $\{2,5,9\}$ because $(\{2,5\}, \{2,5,7\}) \in R$ and $(\{2,5, 7\}, \{2,5,9\}) \in R$.

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for the detailed answer. I'm struggling to understand what $S$ *means*. What's the meaning of the subscripts? If I take $n=1$, then $X=X_0$ and $Y=X_1$, but since there is no $1 \leq i < 1$, then $(X_0,X_1) \notin R$? If $X_0=\{1,2\}$, what is $X_1$?

Comment: @LucasPeres - Sorry, it's a typo, I fixed it now. The index clearly is $0 \leq i < n$. Thus, for $n = 1$, the only possibility is $ i = 0$ and hence $S$ coincides with $R$, which is exactly what we want. Intuitively, $n$ stands for the number of times $R$ is repeated in a sequence: $n = 0$ is the reflexive case, $n = 1$ is $R$, and $n > 1$ is the transitive case.

Comment: By repeated you mean composition? To be more concrete, could you give an example for $n=2$? I know that $(\{1\},\{1,2\}) \in R$ and $(\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}) \in R$, but $(\{1\},\{1,2,3\}) \notin R$, whereas $(\{1\},\{1,2,3\})$ should be in $S$. So I think you'd call $X_0=\{1\}$ and $X_2=\{1,2,3\}$, right? If that is the case, the subscript 2 means I can go from $X_0$ to $X_2$ with two "hops" (don't know a better word)?

Comment: @LucasPeres - Exactly, you got it!

Comment: I see. Putting in words, could we describe $S$ as $(X,Y) \in S$ if and only if $X \subseteq Y$ and $\forall y \in Y(y \text{ is linear combination of } $X$)$?

Comment: @LucasPeres - Perfect, well done! There are few details to fix, but this is the idea. More precisely, $(X, Y) \in S$ if and only if one of the following holds (1) $X = \emptyset = Y$; (2) $\emptyset \neq X, Y \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and for all $y \in Y$ there exist $x_1, \dots, x_k \in X$ such that $y = n_1 \cdot x_1 + \dots + n_k \cdot x_k$ for some $n_1, \dots, n_k \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$. Note that in case (2), the condition $X \subseteq Y$ is included: take $k = 1 = n_1$. If we allow $Y = \emptyset$ in case (2), then $\emptyset$ would be a maximum, contrary to the definition of $R$.